controller class annotated with @RequestMapping doesn't allow you to have a method annotated with @PostMapping inside it
I have a controller class StudentController annotated with @RequestMapping("/students")
@RequestMapping("/students")
@Controller
public class StudentController {}

inside this class I have the following method
@PostMapping("/processForm")
public String processForm ( ) {return "confirmation"; }

but when running the app the method processForm does not execute, and I get "POST is not supported" error. is there a way around it  without changing postmapping to getmapping? thank you.
I tried changing postmapping to getmapping or remove the @RequestMapping("/students") and both worked, but I was wondering if there is other way.

Were you sending a request to /students/processForm?

you are just sending the request to the wrong url
